# Изображения, delphi

Tags: delphi

Вообщем, мне нужно засунуть файлы в один файл который будет путешествовать с программой. В этом файле, должны присутствовать картинки. Также, мне нужно чтобы например **нажав** на одну картинку, вместо неё появлялась другая, из этого файла который я создал в начале.

Comment: А что вы уже сделали для решения вашего вопроса?
Или сколько Вы согласны за решение Вашего вопроса?

Comment: Всмысле сколько? Я думаю над решением этого вопроса уже очень долго. Я не понимаю, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: то что думаете это хорошо, но   этого мало, делать еще чтото нужно, за вас вашу задачу решать не кто не будет.
Пробуйте сами, а вот что не будет получатся мы вам с радостью поможем подскажем.

а пока это работа за вас

Comment: Чушь...ничего не понятно, что тебе нужно...

Comment: если картинки немного , то можно засунуть в **[rc][1]** файл


  [1]: http://www.jansfreeware.com/articles/delphiresource.html

Comment: А если много -- то ресурсы лопнут? Или просто объём .exe будет внушать ужас? В ресурсы их -- и пусть юзер трепещет.

Comment: @alexlz, конечно можно. Но мне лень описывать сотни файлы,которые нужно упаковать в rc =)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как примеров своего кода ты не приводишь, попробую подсказать одно из возможных направлений.

1. Создать DLL в ресурсах которой будут хранится твои картинки, и подгружать их оттуда. И посмотри в MSDN такие функции как: LoadResource LoadBitmap LoadImage...
2. Используй файл базы данных с blob полями для хранения рисунков. Например Access.
3. Использовать файл архива например zip или rar для хранения. Есть достаточно много компонент для работы с архивами либо используй функционал из dll как это предлагает RAR.
4. Разработай свою структуру хранения данных для хранения информации о количестве изображения и хранения оных в файле.

Comment: Есть варианты еще проще, без ДЛЛ, без СУБД, без архивов.
Но товарищь в упор не хочет ничего делать, а просит чтобы сделалали за него, так что пусть ждет.